# Knowing request IP in Hapi.js Restful API

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I'm working on a Restful API with node.js and hapi.js. I'm trying to log the IP of the clients that request one of my routes.

This is my current code:

```
function(request, reply){
    var ip = request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || request.connection.remoteAddress;
    console.log('IP: ' + ip);

    //more code...
}
```

But **ip** is undefined when I watch my logs. 
How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `request.info.remoteAddress` instead of `request.connection.remoteAddress`:

```
var ip = request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || request.info.remoteAddress;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a refinement of the accepted answer that accounts for the fact that the x-forwarded-for header can be a comma-separated set of multiple IP addresses in the case where the request passes through multiple proxy servers.  In such a scenario the client IP will be the leftmost (first) IP address.  This code will handle both possible formats of the header:

```
var xFF = request.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
var ip = xFF ? xFF.split(',')[0] : request.info.remoteAddress;
```

Comment: It is probably better to not trust the first IP address in x-forwarded-for as it could be spoofed by the original requestor. Much better to go backwards in the array depending on the number of proxy servers the request goes through.